# Read CSV with 3 columns and group some elements

Tags: python, datetime, csv

I have a csv with `3 columns (date, name, number)` and it is about 20K rows long. I want to create a dictionary keyed by date whose value is a dictionary of name:number for that date. On top of that, I want add some elements together if the name contains a key word so they would be listed as keyword:sum of numbers, rather than their individual entries.

E.g. If the csv had four entries

```
 6/17/84, Blackcat, 10, 
 6/17/84, Dog, 20, 
 6/17/84, Tabbycat, 12,
 6/17/84, Lizard, 5
```

and the keyword is `cat`, the result should be

```
{6/17/84: {'Dog':20, 'Lizard':5, 'cat':22}}
```

Here's what I came up with. Is there a better way?

```
       import csv
        import operator
        import collections
        import time

            def dict_of_csv(file_name, group_labels_with):
                complete_dict = {}
                key_word = [x.lower() for x in group_labels_with]
                for i in file_name:
                    key = i[1].lower()
                    key_value = int(i[2])
                    row_date = time.strptime(i[0], "%m/%d/%y")
                    if row_date not in complete_dict:
                        complete_dict[row_date] = {}
                        for name in key_word:
                            complete_dict[row_date][name] = 0
                    if any(name in key for name in key_word):
                        for name in key_word:
                            if name in key:
                                key = name
                        complete_dict[row_date][key] += key_value
                    else:
                        complete_dict[row_date][key] = key_value
                return complete_dict

    weeks = open("../DataIn/Master List 14day.csv", "rU")
    real_labels = csv.reader(weeks)

print dict_of_csv(real_labels, ['keyword1', "keyword2", "keyword3"])

weeks.close()
```

Comment: How are you reading in the file?

Comment: I just updated the code to include that. Thanks for pointing out that I didn't mention that part.

Answer (score 3):

The first argument to your function does not appear to be a string holding the name of a file, as its name lead me to initially assume. I would suggest you change to e.g. `csv_reader` (right?) to make it clear what we're getting.

`i` is another bad variable name, it's usually used for an integer index, and doesn't tell the reader anything useful. Also, the following is more meaningful than the current indices into `i`:

```
for date, key, val in csv_reader:
```

You can then apply whatever processing you need and it's still clear what's happening:

```
val = int(val)
```

---

I see what you're trying to do here:

```
if any(name in key for name in key_word):
    for name in key_word:
        if name in key:
            key = name
```

But won't save any time - you have to go through all `name in key_word` once for the `any(...) is False` case, and fully twice in the worst `any(...) is True` case. Just use:

```
for name in key_word:
    if name in key:
        key = name
```

---

[`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) would simplify much of that code for you, for example:

```
complete_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
...
for date, key, val in csv_reader:
    ...
    date = time.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%y")
    for name in key_word:
        ...
    complete_dict[date][key] += val # don't need any checks for keys
```

---

On a logical point, what should happen if a `key` contains more than one `key_word`, or if there are overlaps between `key_word`s? At the moment the first match is used in cases where there are no further complications, but you could `break` to ensure this (and speed up the code).

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks! Especially the idea of 'what if a key contains more than one key_word', because that is very possible.